# Functions may not be defined within control directives or other mixins

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, compass-sass, npm-install

In my nodeJS project suddenly it give error.I do not any upgrade or changes.
When I write NPM start in command line it give that error

```
 ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader?
sourceMap&outputStyle=expanded&includePaths[]=c:/TFS/rc1/app/scss&includePaths[]

=c:/TFS/rc1/~/compass-mixins/lib&sourceMap&sourceMapContents=true!./app/scss/_toolkit.scss
    Module build failed:
    undefined
     ^
          Functions may not be defined within control directives or other mixins.
          in c:\TFS\rc1\node_modules\compass-mixins\lib\compass\functions\_lists.scss (line 81, column 3)
     @ ./app/scss/_toolkit.scss 4:14-337
```

I reinstall compass-mixins package but it still give same error.Then I looked _lists.scss that file in 81 line there is a code .I deleted that bu it give same error.What should I do?

```
@if not(function-exists(compact)) {
  @function compact($vars...) {
    $list: ();
    @each $var in $vars {
        @if $var {
            $list: append($list, $var, comma);
        }
    }
    @return $list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using LibSass or the official Ruby Sass?

Comment: this is react js project not ruby project.How can i check if it is libsass or ruby sass?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of that other stuff you're using, but for Unix or Mac OS, running `sass -v` in the terminal would at least confirm that you have Ruby Sass installed.

Comment: @cimmanon I use windows 8.I try sass -v it is not work.You advise mi to check if sass is install?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use Windows for development (I use a unix virtual machine inside of a Windows host).  I ran the provided code using both Ruby Sass and LibSass, and I only get the error in the Ruby Sass version... so I am a little confused as to why you would use the compass-mixins library instead of just using Compass (they're not the same thing) if you're using Ruby Sass.

Comment: @cimmanon this problem is happening to me too, I got Sass 3.4.19 installed

Comment: @QoP are you use windows?What is cmd command for install sas 3.4.19?

Comment: I think that you have to install Ruby first, then gem install sass

Answer (score 6):

I also face the similar problem. And my project is using [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) and [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins). As heart.cooks.mind points out that, [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) is depending on [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass). And [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) upgrade one of its dependence [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) to version [libsass 3.3.3 Delorean](https://github.com/sass/libsass/releases/tag/3.3.3) since [node-sass 3.5.1](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases).

However, one of [libsass 3.3.3 Delorean](https://github.com/sass/libsass/releases/tag/3.3.3) changes is related to this problem:
['Disallow functions to be defined in control directives or mixins (@mgreter, #1550)'](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1550)

Obviously, _lists.scss in [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins) break this rule. Seems someone raise an [issue](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins/issues/84) to [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins) and they have idea on fixing it.

Before [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins) release the issue fixed version, my temporary workaround is to delete node_modules/node-sass manually and npm install node-sass@3.4.2

Comment: For those with automated builds, this isn't really an option. Adding `"node-sass": "3.4.2"` to `devDependencies` in `package.json` is a better call here. When the breaking change is solved, just removed that line and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,please refer to [node sass release 3.5.3 is breaking build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806485/node-sass-release-3-5-3-is-breaking-build/36806747?noredirect=1#comment61203015_36806747) and force lock gulp-sass to use the specific node sass library using [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) and avoid using the buggy version of node sass

Answer (score 1):

<s>I am using Gulp.  Version 2.3.0 of gulp-sass breaks it.  Go back to Version 2.2.0 and you are all fixed.</s>

Edit:

The real culprit is the node module inside the "gulp-sass" node module known as "node-sass".  You can see inside "gulp-sass"'s package.json file that it simply pulling version greater than ^3.5.3.

Even if you go back and reinstall "gulp-sass" to 2.2.0, as I suggested earlier, the package.json file in there will still pull "node-sass" greater than ^3.5.3.

If I use the older version of "node-sass" 3.4.2 that error goes away.  I don't know how to fix that in an automated way. In a pinch I was able to fix the problem by copying that folder (that is using 3.4.2) from a different project that works.  Now it compiles.

Can someone smarter than me figure out a better way to accomplish this result?

Comment: can you give command please.I am .net developer i am new at the node js -npg envirmont

Comment: Can you clarify how this solves the problem?  Simply getting rid the error message won't help if the function ends up being scoped inside that if-statement.

Comment: Correct.  It does not "solve" the problem.  This is an inherent risk of using Node modules.  Every node module (not just gulp-sass) has its own package.json file.  That will always be pulling greater than ^x.x.x.  In the long run its always a bad idea to fork code that is maintained elsewhere.  It does "solve" the problem for us today, which is important.  But the root problem is an inherent risk of using Node (for our purposes) due to the lack of control over child child dependencies.

Comment: Also I want to point our that using that specific version of "node-sass" is not the root root problem.  It is actually the compass-mixin that it is calling.  Apparently Libsass is getting more strict at what it allows.  Hence the error message "Functions can not be defined within control directives or other mixins".  They used to let this stuff slide, but now they are not.

Comment: I added `"node-sass": "3.4.2"` to `devDependencies` in my `package.json` file (even though I don't specifically need it, `grunt-sass` does) which stops `grunt-sass` from installing `node-sass` and that seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry - actually adding `"node-sass": "3.4.2"` does work. But be careful not to carelessly just type `"^3.4.2"` as I first did. 'Cos that doesn't work.

Comment: I never use `^` or `~` for that very reason. If you work in an environment with automated builds or multiple devs. It pays to be 100% sure everyone is using the same dependencies. Learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

What I (temporarily) did, was to install globally the node-sass v3.4.2, and then replace the gulp-sass version of node-sass (it is located within gulp-sass/node_modules) with this older one.

```
sudo npm install -g node-sass@3.4.2;
sudo cp -r /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/ /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, there is a [PR waiting to be merged](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins/pull/86) for this. But if you want to use this today then there's [a fork of the merge](https://github.com/tjenkinson/compass-mixins) too.
If you want to use latter then just put `compass-mixins: tjenkinson/compass-mixins` in your `package.json` and all will be good.

*Update:- There's also an npm package for the latter mentioned in the [PR](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins/pull/86#issuecomment-218906960) now*

*Update 2:- This should no longer be a problem with v0.12.8 now*

Comment: Upgrading to 0.12.8 fixed it for me.