# node sass release 3.5.3 is breaking build

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

This is also currently biting my project, which uses gulp-sass. gulp-sass depends on node-sass#^3.4.1 which just automatically updated to 3.5.3 which is a breaking release.

I have degraded my gulp sass version to the older(2.1.0) by updating the 
package.json file but its still breaking.

how to go back to node sass 3.4.2?

Error Message

Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
      You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "abcd",
  "devDependencies": {
     "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-bower": "^0.0.7",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-install": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: How does it break? What is the error?

Comment: I have updated the post it is not supporting @extend inside media query.

Comment: What does that have to do with Gulp?  Extend isn't  supposed to work inside media queries.

Comment: That's a wrong concept cinnamon. It worked with older version of node sass. There might be some change in node sass error handler to show this message .If you keep your eyes open all Devs who uses node packages r facing this issue for last 3 days because there was node sass version update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a [new version was just released that allows the "buggy" version of node-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/commit/cfee7560774d8f3c5cde46b42569b8d1d2a15f82) but you can always [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) specific sub-dependencies to a specific version if you need to - assuming that the primary package is compatible with that dependency version.

This will lock the `node-sass` version in `gulp-sass` to 3.4.2:

```json
{
  "name": "yourprojectname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-sass": {
      "version": "2.3.1",
      "from": "gulp-sass@>=2.3.1 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sass/-/gulp-sass-2.3.1.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "node-sass": {
          "version": "3.4.2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you delete your `node_modules` [`npm cache clean`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache) to clear your locally cached packages before running `npm install` again.

Comment: steveax I think its going to work.But can you help me fit this dependency in my package json I mentioned above

Comment: @SudiptoSarkar, that JSON block above doesn't go into your `package.json` but rather in `npm-shrinkwrap.json` (at the same level as your `package.json`).

Comment: Thanks steveax,that worked like a charm and you know what it irrespective of whatever is there in my npm cache,i did not even had to run npm cache clean!!

Comment: So i'm fairly new to this stack and i can't get shrinkwrap to work, i did an npm install to install all the dependancies and then npm install shrinkwrap but when i run command npm shrinkwrap i get the following error:  extraneous: shrinkwrap@0.4.0 C:\dev\xxxx\node_modules\shrinkwrap

Comment: It's good way but I get error: Invalid dependency: gulp-sass {"version":"2.3.1","from":"gulp-sass@>=2.3.1 <3.0.0","resolved":"registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sass/-/…;:{"node‌​-sass":{"version":"3‌​.4.2"}}}